# how to write a formula inside text

Tags: math-mode, text

I need to write this: T_{n} 
instead of this: T(n)

but I'm inside an abstract document

sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia **T_{n}** non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?

so the result is this:

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this should be treatable like any other in-text math:  `$T_{(n)}`.  (i'm assuming that the *n* is in parentheses, even though it's a subscript; the image on my screen isn't very clear.)

Comment: Put the T_{n} like this: `$T_{n}$` between the two dollar signs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Barbara and Abo for the solution, it works fine:

sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia **$T_{n}$** non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?

[image]

Comment: Do you have two accounts? Are you the O.P. named Noomak? If so, please contact the SE staff to get your accounts merged